# Are there disadvantages to @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) in comparison to mock(MyClass.class)?

Tags: mockito, junit5

We are currently discussing whether we should switch our JUnit 5 test classes to `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` with `@Mock`-annotated class members:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SomeTestClass {

    @Mock
    private MyClass aMockedDependency;

}
```

Currently, we define these members without annotation and instantiate them within the `@BeforeEach`-annotated setup method, using `Mockito.mock(MyClass.class)`:

```
class SomeTestClass {

    private MyClass aMockedDependency;

    void setup() {
        aMockedDependency = mock(MyClass.class);
    }

}
```

Adding the MockitoExtension looks like a natural next step. The advantage seems obvious, too: less boilerplate code. But being a thorough engineer I am wondering whether there are disadvantages to it.

My first thought was that it increases the coupling to the test framework. (Tight coupling generally always being a thing to avoid.) However, considering that the test code is riddled with all sorts of `verify`s and similar Mockito-driven functions, this point sounds moot - the coupling is already super-tight anyway and moving away from Mockito would cost considerable effort.

A second thought was that MockitoExtension might be slower. `mock(MyClass.class)` gets all the information it needs to get to work right away while the MockitoExtension first needs to analyze the annotated class to find which members to inject. Indeed in an unrepresentative measurement I observed one test case who had a 1.6 seconds runtime and was nearly 4x slower than the 0.4 seconds runtime it had with .mock(). However, other comparisons don't seem to substantiate that. Are there representative measurements that I can refer to to?

Are there other factors that we should take into account when taking this decision?